# Imitating Gaussian Blur with Smart Blur

Tags: filter, blur

Last year I used a 1% Gaussian Blur for a photo project.
Today I'd like to recreate the same blur effect in a non-destructive way, with the Smart Blur function.

However I'm struggling to find the appropriate Radius, Threshold and Mode settings to approach the 1% Gaussian Blur.

Does anyone know how to convert Gaussian Blur settings to Smart Blur?
Or which Threshold and Mode the smart one uses?

Comment: What applicationa are we talking about? Why dont you apply a gaussian blur nondestructively

Comment: At the end of the day, you probably just have to eyeball it.